# Error: The method 'map' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, object, layout

```
var questions = [
  {
    'questionText' : 'What\'s your favorite colour? ',
    'answers' : [ 'Green', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Black'],
  },
];
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My second app'),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Question(
            questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as String
        ),
        **questions[_questionIndex]['answers'].map((answer){
          return Answer('', answer);
          }),**
```

> I tried to put "as String" but nothing worked, the compiler always returns the same error

Comment: please share your "Answer()" widget class ... what is doing exactly???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let dart know what `questions[_questionIndex]['answers']` is, you can use `as` to do this:

```
(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer){
```